# Как включить продажу услуг на ККТ Штрих-м

Tags: delphi

Через драйвер штриха передаю признак предмета расчета услугу PaymentItemSign := 4 , а в чек все равно идет товар, как исправить ?(

Comment: если строки продажи передаются командой 0х80 то там нет признака. тут tlv нужно...

Comment: Через StringForPrinting

Comment: Я в дельфях не очень. Вот в питоне есть команда sale, которая отправляет 0x80 название, цена, количество. Там признак расчёта не ставится. Вот подпишусь тут под вопросом. Надо будет тоже услуги бить

Comment: Вопрос решился заменой DrvFr.Sale на DrvFr.FNOperation, а  DrvFr.CloseCheck на DrvFr.FNCloseCheckEx, так же в 17 таблице на самом ккт нужно поставить значение 63 в 12 поле.